# Do not let pop up to come up by using back button

Tags: javascript, asp.net, popup

I used pop up in my site.The problem is, when i open a pop up and go to the other page and then go back to previous page, a pop up will refresh and open again!! without any pressed!
How can i fix it?
I want that this pop up wont come up again by coming back to that page.

here is my Pop up code:

```
.......
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.5.3/jquery-ui.min.js" ></script>  
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-1.2.3.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='menu.js'></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
      function pop_up(url) {
          newwindow = window.open(url, 'name', 'height=517,width=885,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,location=no,directories=no,status=no,titlebar=no,left=400,top=120');
          if (window.focus) { newwindow.focus() }
          return false;
      }
    </script>


<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <style type="text/css">
        .style2
        {
.......
```

and behind code:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "popup", "pop_up('" + "PopUpEmailing.aspx" + "');", true);
```

Comment: Registerstartupscript will fire every time. In which event you are handling it ?

Comment: I just put the code in my master page.

Comment: I add it to my question. and also add this pop up code in click event button.

Comment: You want to show the pop_up on a button click event ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to use the `window.name` property.
I know this solution can lead to conflicts if another library also tries to use this.
But I prefer this more then using a cookie. (You could also think over using local storage)

```
function displayPopUp() {
    if( window.name != "popup-displayed" ) {
        window.name = "popup-displayed";
        ... popup code ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript`  try the following.

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnTest" Text="My Button" OnClientClick="pop_up('" + "PopUpEmailing.aspx" + "')"><asp:Button>
```

The above will create a button and when the button will be click a client side event will be called and it will run your pop_up javascript code.